# TypeError method is not a function

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, server, typeerror

I keep getting a TypeError on a GET method on my server.

The exact error is:

```
 TypeError: testCont.createDevice is not a function
```

This isn't usually the way I write my code. The reason I am trying this is so I will be able call routes from different controllers.

This is what the basis of my code looks like.

index.js

It contains all the usual stuff.

This is where I import the controller:

```
 var testCont = require('./api/controllers/testController');
```

And here is my route declaration:

```
 const testRoutes = require('./api/routes/testRoutes');
 testRoutes(app, testCont);
```

testController.js looks like this...

```
 'use strict';
 module.exports = function() {
   var mod = {
     createDevice() {
       return{ success: true }
     }
   }
   return mod;
 };
```

Here is the testRoutes.js class...

```
 module.exports = function(app, testCont) {
   app.get('/api/v1.2/devices', (req, res) => {
     testCont.createDevice()
   })
 };
```

Like I mentioned, the idea would be to eventually call routes from another controller when the information from the response is required.

Does anyone know why it is telling me createDevice is not a function? I've tried so many different things.

Thanks in advance.

UPDATE:

As requested, I am showing the suggested changes implemented.

The index.js looks like this...

```
 var testCont = require('./api/controllers/testController');
 var testRoutes = require('./api/routes/testRoutes');
 testRoutes(app, testCont);
```

When this section of code is commented out, all other calls in the other controllers and routes work fine.

The entire testController.js file looks as follows:

```
 'use strict';
 module.exports = function() {
   createDevice() {
       return{ success: true }
     }
 };
```

The entire testRoutes.js looks as follows:

```
 module.exports = function(app, testCont) {
   app.get('/api/v1.2/devices', (req, res) => {
     testCont.createDevice()
   })
 };
```

When the code is added to the index.js file I get a 502 Bad Gateway error.

UPDATE 2:

I implemented the correction to my oversight...

```
 'use strict';
 module.exports = {
   createDevice() {
       return{ success: true }
     }
  };
```

This is now what it looks like which gets a 504 Gateway Time-out.

Comment: It seems in testController.js , you are exporting a function and in  testRoutes.js you are trying to access createDevice() on the function. quickfix :-   testCont().createDevice();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way your testController.js is written, you would have to change this:

```
var testCont = require('./api/controllers/testController');
```

to this:

```
var testCont = require('./api/controllers/testController')();
```

The `.createDevice()` method is not on the exported object.  It's on the object that the exported function returns WHEN YOU CALL IT.  So, you have to either change the way the exports works so it directly exports the object or you have to call the function to get to the object it returns.

---

Or, you could just change the export to directly export the object by changing it from this:

```
'use strict';
 module.exports = function() {
   var mod = {
     createDevice() {
       return{ success: true }
     }
   }
   return mod;
 };
```

to this:

```
'use strict';
 module.exports = {
     createDevice() {
       return{ success: true }
     }
   }
 };
```

Comment: I tried both of those ways but unfortunately neither are working for some reason.

Comment: @MarcBlazyk - Then, you either didn't implement what I suggested correctly or you also have something else wrong in the full code.  We can't really help further with modified code you haven't shared with us.  These are a solution to the specific problem you first asked about with the code you showed.

Comment: The code works perfectly fine when you remove all of what I have posted. Therefore that would suggest the problem is with the block of code I posted.

Comment: @MarcBlazyk - Add an edit to the end of your question that shows how you modified your code to incorporate this answer and show exactly what error you get with that modified code.  You're asking us to tell you why your modified code (that you don't show us) isn't working.  We can't help you with code we can't see.

Comment: Of course, thats totally fair. Two mins and I will post. Thank you.

Comment: @MarcBlazyk - Your version of `testController.js` is not what I suggested.  You are again exporting a function from `testController.js` that returns the object you want (when called), but never calling that function.  So, you're trying to call `createDevice()` on the exported function, but that function doesn't have such as property.  Only the object that the function returns has that property.  In my second option, I suggested you export an object, not a function. Please attempt to understand exactly what is happening here and what I suggested so you can follow these kinds of issues yourself.

Comment: Sorry, that was a total oversight on my part. I reimplemented as you can see from UPDATE 2.

Comment: @MarcBlazyk - Now, you need to send a response to the request back to the caller, probably something like changing `testCont.createDevice()` to `res.json(testCont.createDevice())`.

Comment: Life saver!! It is all making more sense now! Thank you so much!!